# How to protect my laptop from power surges while travelling abroad?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I protect my laptop from power surges?](https://superuser.com/questions/17496/how-do-i-protect-my-laptop-from-power-surges)

Most of the outlets in south east Asia are non-grounded. Additionally the electrical wiring and power grid standards here are different so it's not the same as back home. There is a also a rainy seasons which can produce many thunder storms. I suppose the best thing to do while it is raining is to simply unplug the charger as not much can help if lightning strikes a shelter with non grounded wiring.

Comment: You've kinda answered your own question; just unplug your laptop's power cord from the wall jack whenever theres a storm raging outside. If you have the money you can also get yourself a mini UPS (uninterruptible power supply) which can acts as a surge protector and has a battery that will give your laptop enough juice so you can save all your important documents in time. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I've answered part of my question. The other issue though is when power surges happen due to poor grid standards, which I believe happens too often here.

Comment: And I've covered that part on my comment also. :) Get yourself a good mini UPS, don't be cheap. The really good ones does not only have built-in surge protector but also has built-in high and low voltage fluctuation protections too. (Lived in Asia for 3 years)

Comment: Not a problem sir. Oh and get yourself some mosquito repellent while you're getting your UPS. :) Have a safe trip.

Comment: And try http://superuser.com/questions/226907/protecting-a-laptop-in-a-surge-ridden-area